# getting image from link in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a link to an image an I would like to save it as an image.
For example the link is http://graph.facebook.com/sarfraz.anees/picture. How do I save this into an image variable in javascript so I can use it to do:

```
document.write("<img src=\"" + pic + "\" class=\"avatar\">")
```

also would be very useful if someone can guide me on how to resize this image to a 50x50.
Here's my latest code

**UPDATE:**

```
<body id="suggestions" class="default verified ">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({appId: '1355709392349404', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.session) {
                pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.session.uid + "/picture";
              } else {
                window.location = "index.php"
              }
            });
    </script>
    <div class="clearfix" id="wrap">
        <div id="nav">
            <div class="center clearfix">
                <h5>
                    <a href="/main.php">Favor</a>
                </h5>
                <ul class="icons menu clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <a title="You" href="/me">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                document.write("<img src=\"" + pic + "\" class=\"avatar\">");
                            </script>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Issue is that I can't get the pic that is on the other script

Comment: When you say that you "have" a link, what do you mean?  What "has" it? If you know the image URL, why not just type in an `<img>` tag?

Comment: Now where have I seen that face before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with just:

```
document.write('<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/sarfraz.anees/picture" class="avatar">');
```

or...

```
var pic = 'http://graph.facebook.com/sarfraz.anees/picture';
document.write("<img src=\"" + pic + "\" class=\"avatar\">")
```

??  And it's already a 50x50 image...

Comment: I got a pic not defined in my console window. I have defined var pic = url to image in the head. This is dynamic and in the body I do the write

Answer (score 0):

```
var pic = document.createElement('img');
pic.className = 'avatar';
pic.src = 'sourcetopicture.png';
pic.height = '50';
pic.width = '50';

document.body.appendChild(pic);
```

Just substitute where you'd like to append the picture. For instance, if it were a `div` with the id of `myDiv`, you could say

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(pic);
```

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: I think the issue is with variable scoping.. I have updated the question above